# Does the fixed point functor preserve colimit and limit?

Tags: category-theory, lie-groups, limits-colimits, equivariant-maps

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $g\in G$. Let $C_G(g)$ denote the centralizer of $g$ in $G$. 
Consider the functor $X\mapsto X^g$ from the category of $G-$spaces to the category of $C_G(g)-$spaces.

Does this functor preserve colimits? Does it preserve limits?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I just tried to prove it by definition. Say L is a colimit of a diagram in the category of G-spaces, I hope L^g is a colimit of the corresponding diagram in the category of C_G(g)-spaces....but failed.

Comment: It preserves limits but not all colimits. Hint: Suppose $g=e$, $X$ has no fixed points, and $X\to C$ is a regular epi (coequalizer map) such that $C$ has fixed points. You should be able to verify the limits statements directly, using an explicit construction of limits.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to solve it myself.